# Debian 9 sources.list

Tags: debian, software-updates

I have installed Debian 9 Stretch stable version today.

I want to update my system. But I didn't find package list for sources.list. In the site, I found Debian 9 sources.list package. But this list for Debian 9 Testing. Can I use it for stable Debian 9? or where is Debian 9 sources.list?

How can I update my system?

Debian 9 was released yesterday. Do I need to update the system?

Comment: I just installed Debian 9, sources.list says "stretch", not "testing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sources.list` for Debian Testing is not compatible with Debian 9 (codename *Stretch*)

Here is an example `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

The following `sources.list` attempts to serve content close to your location using redirection:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

To update your system, proceed as usual:

```
apt-get update # Update package information from sources
apt-get upgrade # Upgrade packages
apt-get dist-upgrade # Upgrade packages that depends on new dependencies
```

I do recommend doing security updates either manually or doing it as part of planned upgrades via other provisioning systems, *after testing in a pre-production environment*. In alternative, you might also install the package `unattended-upgrades`.

You can read more information [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)

Comment: Thanks!. Hey Rui, i have a last question. How can i install nvidia driver? When i use Debian 8.8, i can install it from here https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Version_340.96. is it possible for Debian 9?

Comment: @FarugYer You will have to experiment or wait for them to update your linked page. Unfortunately I only manage a couple hundred Debian VMs only with text mode and my laptop is actually running OpenBSD so someone more used to Nvidia can help you more. I would open another question about that.