# apt update 400 error on Debian 9 image

Tags: debian, apt, docker

I'm working on a debian:9 image pulled from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/). When I ran `apt update` or `apt-get update`, I got the following error messages:

```
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease          
Err:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release      
 400  Bad request: request method denied
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                  
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
 400  Bad request: request method denied
Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release    
 400  Bad request: request method denied
Reading package lists... Done                                  
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My `sources.list` file looks like this (official example from [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main    
deb-src http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main
```

I also tried other releases, but got the same error. Does anyone have a clue what might cause the problem? Many thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks to [GracefulRestart](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/281407/gracefulrestart), I finally solved it by manually setting the network proxy for the Debian image in Dockerfile before I do `apt update`.

Although the question is marked as duplicate, it has nothing to do with [Debian: The repository does not have a Release file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371890/286578), because it was 400 error and the `sources.list` file was actually correct.

Comment: I've seen that post before, but that answer didn't help.

Comment: I just pulled that debian docker image and did not have those issues.  Are you doing some non-default networking in your docker environment?

Comment: @GracefulRestart I never configured networking manually for the contrainer... :/

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is then, a 400 error means you were able to connect to the remote HTTP server but it rejected your request.  Unless you modified the docker image, I should have the same `debian:latest` that you do.  I am not able to replicate your problem, are you running behind some proxy that would modify your requests in some way?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Thanks for reminding me about that! I finally solved it by modifying the webproxy in my Dockerfile.

Comment: @GracefulRestart if you'd like to write it as an answer, I will accept it :) 'cause I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question right now

Comment: I cannot seem to post an answer, this question appears to be locked as a duplicate but the linked answer has nothing to do with misconfigured proxies.  Not sure if i can fix that.

Comment: @GracefulRestart I didn't understand why so many people marked it as duplicate without reading the question even after I explained it was something different. I just wrote the solution in my question, hopefully someone sees it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[Debian 9 sources.list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371865/debian-9-sources-list)
The sources.list for Debian Testing is not compatible with Debian 9 (codename Stretch)

Here is an example sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

The following sources.list attempts to serve content close to your location using redirection:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

To update your system, proceed as usual:

```
apt-get update # Update package information from sources
apt-get upgrade # Upgrade packages
apt-get dist-upgrade # Upgrade packages that depends on new dependencies
```

I do recommend doing security updates either manually or doing it as part of planned upgrades via other provisioning systems, after testing in a pre-production environment. In alternative, you might also install the package unattended-upgrades.

Comment: Yeah I knew it's the example provided by Debian Wiki, already tried that URL before. Adding contrib and non-free didn't change anything either.

Comment: Check the URL opens in browser or not

Comment: Check ftp.us.Debian.org in browser

Comment: I can actually open http://deb.debian.org/debian/ in browser, and for me http://ftp.de.debian.org/ too. Can also do `apt update` on a real Debian 9 machine with the exactly same `sources.list`. I will edit the question.

Comment: Pls check this http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/

Comment: From `sources.list` Remove the repositories which do not work. Keep only those which work.

Comment: Try with https instead of http

Comment: Thanks for the help! It turned out to be a network configuration problem

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept this solution. If you have solved by yourself please provide the solution as answer so that other people might get help.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, so I will post the solution in my question soon.